# make link - object data but keep original scale

Tags: modeling, scale, instances

i have a city layout made of cubes of diffent sizes. im trying to replace those cubes with some building models while keeping the size of the cube.

the tool make link(object data) get me close to what i want but its not keeping the original scale of my cubes. if the scale of the cube is set in object mode the scale is way too big. if the scale of the cube is set in edit mode the cube take the exact scale of the building model.

[image]

[image]

so basically i would like to have each boxes replaced by the model but keep their dimensions.

any idea how i could achieve this ?